# I cannot mount the container I created with Docker Compose to a folder in my local, what's wrong?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-image

I am running a simple application using Node.js and Express. I am trying to create a Docker image of the application and create a container with the image using Docker Compose. I want to mount the files in the workspace in the resulting container (in this case index.js, package.json and other files) to ./test in the directory where the docker-compose.yml file is located, but I get an error.

### Source Code

#### index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Docker Compose!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-node-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

#### Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY index.js /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am building the application with the command:

```
docker build -t express-app:latest .
```

In another folder named test-app, I run the following docker-compose.yml file with the command `docker compose up`.

The files in the workdir in the container do not come to the ./test folder and I get the following error.

```
Attaching to test-app-express-app-1
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! syscall open
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! errno -2
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! enoent
test-app-express-app-1  |
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-11-17T15_23_04_691Z-debug.log
test-app-express-app-1 exited with code 254
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me?

#### docker-compose.yml

This yml file is what I want to run

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  express-app:
    container_name:test
    image: express-app:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./test:/app
```

This yml file works, but it does not do a mount operation in the directory where I work:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  express-app:
    container_name:test
    image: express-app:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - test:/app
volumes:
   test:
```

This yaml file is the docker-compose.yml file for the image of a nodejs headless cms application called Strapi

```
version: '3'

services:
  strapi:
    container_name: strapi
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=strapi
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: 'strapi start'

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: strapi
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapi
      POSTGRES_DB: strapi
```

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the Compose file in your question.  If you're using `volumes:` to replace the image's entire `/app` directory with code from the host, then you're not really testing anything in your image at all, and you might find it easier to use Node without Docker to run tests like this.

Comment: I am attaching the docker-compose.yml file to the question

Comment: In both Compose setups, the `volumes:` block hides everything in the `/app` directory, including its `package.json` file.  I'd recommend deleting that.  If you're looking at running unit tests, I'd do that using your non-Docker development environment, before you `docker build` an image.

Comment: So, why is there no such problem when I use an old sample yaml file of Strapi? It mounts the app and database files in the local directory? I am attaching that sample yaml file to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no `package.json` in your builded image.
when you type `docker build -t express-app:latest`.
haven't you got error from building docker image?

like following error from console.

```
 => ERROR [3/4] COPY package.json /app
```

you can modify your dockerfile to figure out what is inside when docker compose up.

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY test.js /app

CMD "tail -f /dev/null"
```

after docker compose up,
then type `docker ps` to see running docker process,
type to get sh `docker exec -it [docker-name] /bin/sh`.

### update answer for detail things

1. create test package.json  and test.js

```json
{
    "hi" : "hello"
}
```

```js
console.log('hi')
```

2. create dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY test.js /app
```

3. build image and run it
   make sure use your custom tags not latest (for convenience).

```
docker build -f dockerfile -t express-app:local . 
docker run -dit --name express express-app:local

docker ps 
## check container's running
```

execute container's bin/sh and check app has package, test.js

```
docker exec -it express /bin/sh
# ls
package.json  test.js
# pwd
/app
```

4. now build docker-compose from image

not to confuse app, I change another mount volume to loaded

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mycustom:
    container_name: mycustom
    image: express-app:local
    volumes:
      - ./loaded:/app/loaded
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

5. check container contains folder and test.js, package.json

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-copmose.yaml up 
// go to another terminal
docker exec -it mycustom /bin/sh

docker exec -it mycustom /bin/sh

# pwd
/app
# ls
loaded  package.json  test.js
```

Comment: There is no problem with the docker image. When I run "docker run -p 3000:3000 express-app:latest" cantainer works fine. My problem is that I can't mount the files in workdir to a local file

Comment: `test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! errno -2
test-app-express-app-1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'` your log says you don't have files inside container.

Comment: My goal is to create an image with Docker. I successfully create this image and with this image I can create a container without assigning a volume and use it successfully. I cannot connect the volume I created with docker compose to the local folder, the files do not come.

Mr. Jeong Yo Han, could you check my source code by trying it on your own computer? I am sure you will get the same error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The method you show works. At least the way you want to do it. It connects the folder named loaded to the container. I would like to ask you the following: Can I transfer the files in the container to my local folder, like linking "test.js, package.json, node_modules" files to the test folder in my directory.

Comment: @MustafaTunahanTuna you mean .. `docker cp` or you just want to mount container's volume on host machine without replacing it with host machine volume ??

Comment: I want to connect the container to the host without changing its unit to the host unit